# Why is this subquery NULL in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
for (var i=0; i<req.files.length; i++) {
        await sequelize.query(
            `INSERT INTO images (path, priority, saleId) VALUES (
                "${req.files[i].filename}",
                (SELECT max FROM (SELECT MAX(priority)+1 AS max FROM images WHERE saleID = ${req.query.saleId}) AS temp),
                ${req.query.saleId})`
        )
}
```

I wanna get max value in subquery.
But, this subquery contains the query statement itself, not the value.
and sqlMessage is "Column 'priority' cannot be null".
How can i get max value?
This query working well in MySQL. but, not working in Sequelize.

[image]

This is "select * from images" result.

[image]

This is error message.

Comment: Please post of `select * from images` 's result.
On my side, your script is working well

Comment: I add that result and error message. Check it please. It working well in MySQL but not working in Sequelize.